# Auto Comment (e.g. "///") but not in XML in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, comments, auto-generate

I like the "///" feature in visual studio just fine, but I find the fact that it is displayed in XML, is disorienting. I would much rather have the output look something like javadocs:

```
/**
 * @author      Firstname Lastname <address @ example.com>
 * @version     1.6                 (current version number of program)
 * @since       2010-03-31          (version of the package this class was first added to)
 */
```

Is there some way of achieving this? I do not care that the data may not be accessible outside of the app (e.g. auto generated API documents). I simple want this so that I and another person looking at the code can see some concise and uniform comments for each function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Snippet to include your own comment style using a keyboard shortcut.

[Snippet editor](http://snippeteditor.codeplex.com/) is a handy tool to do this.

However, If those other users are used to working in Visual studio and C# then *they* would be disoriented by looking at any other way of commenting other than the XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's *technically* a way to do this, but you'd be writing an extension to Visual Studio yourself to format the XML comments visually in VS while maintaining the original format in your source files.

Something like the WPF-based viewer at the end of [this XML comments article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx#id0400079) (which I believe was only an internal prototype).

I haven't seen extensions that do this in the Visual Studio Gallery.  Perhaps the closest in concept is [ItalicComments](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0b439a8a-e21a-4e26-b82b-054fbf0acab7), but that's not what you're after.